# rails link_to prints itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have this in my html page

```
<%= link_to "bla", "www.google.com" %>
```

and when I hit localhost:3000 I get this

```
<%= link_to "bla", "www.google.com" %>
```

PS: I'm new to rails. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your view file name has the html.erb extension.

For example, for a User model, the model is in `app/models/user.rb`, the controller is in `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`, and the show view is in `app/views/users/show.html.erb`.

I hope this helps.